# How to configure Tab visibility on Lightning App builder to be based on a boolean attribute of the record type

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-apps

I was wondering if it were possible to have a custom tab's visibility in the Lightning app builder be dependent on an editable boolean attribute on the record?

i.e  as soon as a checkbox on the Details tab is ticked, the 'BOOLEAN VISIBILIY' tab is either created or becomes visible.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the documentation available and as far as I can see it during my usage/tests, there's **no** way as of now to be able to do so. You cannot dynamically render or hide a tab which are already added in the Tabs component in Lightning App Builder.

At this point of time, you can only set the visibility of the component itself as to show it only when specific conditions meet. But that too is applicable for all tabs within the component and not for any selective tab. Below is a sample screenshot of the available options when you configure a Tab component in the Lightning App Builder.

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUhW3.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have another idea. Instead of controlling visibility for tab, why not duplicating the tabs component for every Record type and set the component visibility for each record type?

In this case we could achieve the desired outcome which would look like conditional tab rendering, but in fact this will be conditional component rendering.

Create two tabs component, the first one with tabs "Related" and "Detail" and the other one with tabs "Related", "Detail" and custom tab.

Set the visibility for the tab component itself to the desired record type for the second tab component and the opposite (not equal to desired record type) on the first tab component